# Problems with Vaadin components

Tags: css, intellij-idea, vaadin

When I execute this simple Vaadin example (auto generated code) with Idea14.

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);

    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(button);
}
```

I receive this output:
[screenshot](http://gyazo.com/40e3b8b8f3e60cd1cb4ab0eddc7f2029)

I expected a button with CSS. 
**What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is not able to download the theme of your application.

Do you have the `vaadin-themes` dependency added to your project?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My project is neither Maven and Ant project. It's simple WebApplication with linked Vaadin jars.

Comment: @Dmitry then add the theme jar there

Comment: When using custom components you will also have to recompile the widgetset